# doesn't work incorrect canvas with unity integration

Tags: jquery, canvas, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I try to add image element in canvas like ad banner.

```
string injection = @"$(""<div id=""UpperBanner""><img src=""http://mydomain.com/adbanner.png""></div>"").insertbefore(""#unityPlayerEmbed"");";

Application.ExternalEval(injection);
```

but, it doesn't work.

there are no image in canvas.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After unquoting, your string comes out to

```
$("<div id="UpperBanner"><img src="http://mydomain.com/adbanner.png"></div>").insertbefore("#unityPlayerEmbed");
```

The syntax-highlighting should help you see the issue with that :)